# Flash: how do I apply an actionscript script to an existing movie

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a working script on the one hand (in a working movie) and a flash movie on the other.

The script handles a form, I changed the names of elements in the target movie as appropriate.

The source movie contains only one layer and one frame. The target movie contains multiple layers and plays an animation before displaying the form.

How do I go about making the script work on the target movie?

Edit:

I've made some progress, the textfield works, but the button produces exceptions:

```
Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

The name of the button and the variable are the same.

Comment: What version of actionscript is this?  How are you loading one movie into the other?  Can you add some code showing what you tried, what works, and what doesn't?

Comment: As3. It works if I change the type of the button to Movie but then the text on the button blinks.

Comment: I see now that is because the button is a 4 frame "movie". It doesn't explain the NullPointerException though.

Comment: try making the names of the button and the variable separate. They're 2 different assets, so they shouldn't be the same name. The error itself usually comes up when you try to access a variable or visual asset when there isn't one. Is the button on the stage of your movie? If that's the thing that's null, you might be able to access it like so var btn = stage.getChildByName('myClipName') - then use btn as the reference for btn.addEventListener(something...)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code or at least the functionality you're trying to achieve it's difficult to be more specific, but null pointer exceptions are caused by trying to access an object that doesn't exist, usually because it doesn't exist yet.

Either the object is instantiated on later frames than the one the script is on, or it didn't finish initialising itself yet (for example, movieclips don't instantiate the children until they are added to the stage), or it is already garbarge collected and doesn't exist anymore.